# The batch request must have a "Content-Type" header / "multipart/mixed" as the media type

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

Got an error after I add the DefaultODataBatchHandler on my WEB API OData v4.

```
DefaultODataBatchHandler defaultODataBatchHandler = new DefaultODataBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer);
```

In browser I've got this error: **The batch request must have a "Content-Type" header.**
In POSTMan I've got this error: **The batch request must have 'multipart/mixed' as the media type.**

If I didn't put the code above. I've got this error when accessing the **$batch**

```
"Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:2288/$batch'.",
"MessageDetail": "No route providing a controller name was found to match request URI 'http://localhost:2288/$batch'"
```

RouteConfig.cs

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {

        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you add the route to the RoutesConfig?

Comment: I updated my post and I include the routeconfig.

Answer (score 0):

Got it now.

I just need to add CORS

```
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(
            "*",
            "*",
            "*",
            "*"
        );

        config.EnableCors(cors);
```

And put wildcard for the exposed header.